# GE gas dryer noise - is this from motor?

Tags: dryer, electric-motor, troubleshooting

Hi I'm trying to fix my 13 year old dryer. It's started to have squeaking noise but I was able to fix that by replacing the front and rear bearing. Now it's starting to have this noise and I think this is possibly from the motor based on some search on the Internet. But the motor has no problem starting the spin at all, it starts as soon as I hit the switch. Can anyone confirm this is noise from the motor? The video has the recorded noise https://youtu.be/AzQQwjan0LQ Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

No Ted, I believe it is the dryers blower that's creating the sound. The blower pushes the hot air into the dryer. I may be hearing things but to me it sounded as if an article of clothing may be stuck inside the blower and is causing the "fluttering" noise you hear.  Since you are familiar with fixing the dryer bearings, unplug the power cord and then open the dryer case to get to the blower in the back. Look for any obstructions (lint, socks..).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ojait, it sounds like the blower is struggling to exhaust. Also, check that the vent hose or pipe & actual exterior exhaust outlet are all clear.